# Majoring sum with factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, absolute-value, upper-lower-bounds

<sub>EDIT: sorry for all the crappy formulas, I tried to add the more context I can, I hope it is better.</sub>

---

I am currently trying to analytically bound the following term:
$$
\left\vert\left\vert e^{\lambda (H_0 + H_1)} - S_2(\lambda)\right\vert\right\vert
$$
with 
$$
S_2(\lambda) = e^{\frac{\lambda}{2}H_0}e^{\lambda H_1}e^{\frac{\lambda}{2}H_0}
$$
for $H_0$ and $H_1$ two non-commuting matrices with the following properties:

- $H_0^2 = H_1^2 = I$
- $\Lambda = \max \left\{ \vert\vert H_0\vert\vert, \vert\vert H_1\vert\vert \right\} = \vert\vert H_0\vert\vert = \vert\vert H_1\vert\vert = 1$.

My final goal is to bound the following error
$$
\left\vert\left\vert e^{\lambda (H_0 + H_1)} - S_2\left(\frac{\lambda}{r}\right)^r\right\vert\right\vert \leqslant g\left(\lambda, \Lambda, r\right) \leqslant \epsilon
$$
by a function $g$ and to solve $g\left( \lambda, \Lambda, r \right) \leqslant \epsilon$ for $r$ to obtain an expression of $r$ as:
$$
r = h\left( \lambda, \Lambda, \epsilon \right).
$$

I currently have 2 bounds that are far from optimal from [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10980) (Section F.1, page 24-26):
$$
r^{\text{analytic}} = \left\lceil \max \left\{ 4 \Lambda \vert\lambda\vert, \sqrt{\frac{\left(4 \Lambda \vert\lambda\vert\right)^3}{3\epsilon}} \right\} \right\rceil
$$
and
$$
r^{\text{minimized}} = \min \left\{ r \in \mathbb{N}^* : \frac{\left(4 \Lambda \vert\lambda\vert\right)^3}{3r^2} \exp\left(\frac{4 \Lambda \vert\lambda\vert}{r}\right) \leqslant \epsilon \right\}.
$$

During the mathematical development of the error term I stumbled upon a mathematical expression that I failed to major finely enough to obtain a usable error bound:
$$
\left\vert\left\vert e^{\lambda (H_0 + H_1)} - S_2(\lambda)\right\vert\right\vert \leqslant \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \vert\lambda\vert^n \Lambda^n \left[ \frac{2^n-1}{n!} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2n!}  + f(n)\right]
$$
with 
$$
f(n) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-j} \left\vert \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{2^{n-j} i! j! (n-j-i)!} \right\vert.
$$

Using the triangle inequality, I ended up with

$$
f(n) \leqslant \frac{n(n+1)}{2 n!} + \frac{2^n - 1}{n!}
$$
by using the identity
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{n!}{i! (n-i)!} = 2^n
$$
which leads to
$$
\left\vert\left\vert e^{\lambda (H_0 + H_1)} - S_2(\lambda)\right\vert\right\vert \leqslant 2 \left[ e^{2\vert\lambda\vert\Lambda} - e^{\vert\lambda\vert \Lambda} \right].
$$
and finally to
$$
\begin{align}
\left\vert\left\vert e^{\lambda (H_0 + H_1)} - S_2\left(\frac{\lambda}{r}\right)^r\right\vert\right\vert &\leqslant r \left\vert\left\vert e^{\lambda (H_0 + H_1)} - S_2\left(\frac{\lambda}{r}\right)\right\vert\right\vert\\
&\leqslant g(\lambda, \Lambda, r) = 2r e^{\vert\lambda\vert\Lambda / r} \left( e^{\vert\lambda\vert\Lambda / r} - 1 \right).  \\
\end{align}
$$

The main problem with $g(\lambda, \Lambda, r)$ is that its limit when $r \to +\infty$ is not $0$ (it is $2\Lambda\vert\lambda\vert$), so I will not be able to solve $g\left( \lambda, \Lambda, r \right) \leqslant \epsilon$ for $r$ as this equation might have no solution.

My question is then, do you have an idea on how I could compute a better bound?

Comment: That expression goes to $0$ very rapidly as $n$ increases, so perhaps you ought to tell us what values of $n$ you are interested in, and how small a bound you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: I will add the whole context in the next few hours, sorry for the missing information.

Comment: I added a few material based on quick and dirty regressions for your small numbers.

Answer (score 1):

*This is too long for a comment.*

Reading the post, I have been wondering about the meaning of the vertical bars in the definition of $f(n)$.

If it is
$$f(n) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-j} \left( \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{2^{n-j} i! j! (n-j-i)!} \right)$$ we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-j} \left( \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{2^{n-j} i! j! (n-j-i)!} \right)=\frac{n+1-j}{n!}-\frac{1}{j! (n-j)!}$$ which makes
$$f(n)=\frac{n^2+n-2^{n+1}+2}{2 n!}$$ and then
$$\left[ \frac{2^n-1}{n!} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2n!}  + f(n)\right]=0$$

**Edit**

If we consider
$$f(n) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-j} \left\vert \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{2^{n-j} i! j! (n-j-i)!} \right\vert$$ and compute the value of $f(n)$ for the range $3 \leq n \leq 250$, a quick and dirty regression for the model
$$\log[f(n)]=a+b n^c +d n^{2c}$$ which is equivalent to the minimization of
$$SSQ=\sum _{n=3}^{250} \left| \frac{\Delta f(n)}{f(n)}\right|^2$$ we have (with $R^2=0.999998$)
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +6.666622 & 0.199625  & \{+6.273405,+7.059838\} \\
 b & -0.671761 & 0.006089  & \{-0.683754,-0.659767\} \\
 c & +1.329758 & 0.001918  & \{+1.325979,+1.333537\} \\
 d & +0.000030 & \approx 0 & \{+0.000029,+0.000030\} \\
\end{array}$$
Similarly, using the same model for 
$$g(n)=\left[ \frac{2^n-1}{n!} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2n!}  + f(n)\right]$$

$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & +4.126499 & 0.156637  & \{+3.817960,+4.435038\} \\
 b & -0.732346 & 0.005281  & \{-0.742749,-0.721943\} \\
 c & +1.313991 & 0.001539  & \{+1.310961,+1.317022\} \\
 d & +0.000032 & \approx 0 & \{+0.000031,+0.000032\} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The vertical bars are absolute values, that is why I tried the triangle inequality, without success. The absolute value comes from the fact that I normed the whole sum and used: $||A+B||\leqslant ||A||+||B||$, $||AB|| \leqslant ||A||||B||$ (for the spectral norm I am using) and $||\lambda A|| = |\lambda| ||A||$ (the coefficient in the sum is the $\lambda$ here).

Comment: @Nelimee. I am sorry !

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea! I tested it, and I will edit my question to include this idea. The result is not better than the 2 bounds from the paper linked in the question, but is way better than my previous bound!